# MVC 4 Null Data on Post

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am clearly missing something here, and I can't for the life of me figure out what.
I can populate the model just fine and send it to the view, but on post, most of the data is null or default.

I'm force feeding the Create GET with /Test/Create?a1=5&a2=6&shell=7
which works fine to initialize the test entity. POST has the Name and CatId but the other properties are null.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Model

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public partial class TestEntity
    {
        [DisplayName("Entity Id")]
        [Required]
        public int? EntityId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Entity Name")]
        public string EntityName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Category Id")]
        [Required]
        public int? CatId { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Attribute 1")]
        public int? Attribute1 { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Attribute 2")]
        public int? Attribute2 { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

View

```
@model MyApp.Models.TestEntity

<h2>Test</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EntityName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EntityName)
    </p>
    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CatId)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CatId)
    </p>

    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Attribute1)
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Attribute1)
    </p>

    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Attribute2)
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Attribute2)
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Done" />
```

}

Controller

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MyApp.Models;

namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Test/Create
        public ActionResult Create(int? a1, int? a2, int? shell)
        {
            using (var db = new MyDbContext())
            {
                ShellEntity temp =
                    db.ShellEntities.Where(se => se.ShellId == shell).FirstOrDefault();

            TestEntity model = new TestEntity();
            model.CatId = temp.category; //get the category id from the shell
            model.Attribute1 = a1;
            model.Attribute2 = a2;
            return View(model);
            }
        }

        //
        // POST: /Test/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(TestEntity model)
        {
            try
            {
                //at this point model.Attribute1 and Attribute2 are both null
                if (!model.Attribute1.HasValue)
                {
                    //WTF???
                }
                return View(model);
            }
            catch
            {
                return View(model);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the DisplayFor template look like, if any?

Comment: <p>
        <label for="Attribute2">Attribute 2</label>
        6
    </p>

Comment: You cannot use the `Display(For)` method to create html INPUT elements.  The only built-in methods to create html INPUT elements are `Editor(For)` and `Hidden(For)`.

Comment: That's the idea. I want to show the attributes, but not allow the user to change the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Attribute1)
```

to pass values to the controller instead of `DisplayFor()`

Comment: I was hoping to not have to do that for the class with 30+ properties, but oh well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change this code

```
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Attribute1)
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Attribute1)
</p>

<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Attribute2)
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Attribute2)
</p>
```

to this:

```
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Attribute1)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Attribute1)
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Attribute1)
</p>

<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Attribute2)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Attribute2)
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Attribute2)
</p>
```

and it should work fine.

Basically it added `<input name="Attribute1" value="your_value"/>` so it will be included to your `POST` after you click submit button.

Comment: I was hoping to not have to do that for the class with 30+ properties, but oh well. Thanks!